# Change drawRect output depending on device orientation

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation, drawrect

I want to use drawRect to draw 6 boxes which will be used as the background for the output of 6 labels I have setup - when the device's orientation is changed I need to change where the boxes are drawn... I was thinking of doing an if-else statement like below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.611, 0.505, 0.321, 1.0); // Goldie brown colour
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(70, 277, 35, 50)); // Years
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(145, 277, 35, 50)); // Months
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(220, 277, 35, 50)); // Days
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(70, 393, 35, 50)); // Hours
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(145, 393, 35, 50)); // Minutes
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(220, 393, 35, 50)); // Seconds
} else {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.611, 0.505, 0.321, 1.0); // Goldie brown colour
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(87, 221, 35, 50)); // Years
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(162, 221, 35, 50)); // Months
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(234, 221, 35, 50)); // Days
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(308, 221, 35, 50)); // Hours
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(385, 221, 35, 50)); // Minutes
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(466, 221, 35, 50)); // Seconds
 }
```

but this wont work because (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) needs a parameter/constant declaring & it doesnt look like I can do that here - is there something similar I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it by using

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
```

or by changing a flag (e.g. `BOOL shouldDrawPortrait`) in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` of your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

When will device change the orientation, in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, you must call at method `setNeedDisplay` of `UIView`.

ex: `[box1 setNeedDisplay];`